# Spring integration chain error block process

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm trying to handle errors using the int:poller, I defined an error-channel on the poller  when an error occurs the ErrorHandler invoked, but it still executed in a loop and 
block the principal process that handle the next correct message.
Here's my config any ideas?

```
<int:outbound-channel-adapter ref="cvsMessageHandler" method="handleMessage" channel="cvsInputChannel"/>
<int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" id="defaultPoller" default="true" fixed-rate="5000"
            error-channel="cvsErrorChannel">
    <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</int:poller>

<bean id="cvsMessageHandler" class="com.cvs.ws.wrapper.MessageHandler">
</bean>


<int:channel id="cvsErrorChannel"/>

<bean id="cvsErrorMessageHandler" class="com.eplatform.transverse.cvs.ws.service.ErrorHandler">
    <property name="eventService" ref="cvsEventService"/>
    <property name="eventFactory" ref="cvsEventFactory"/>
</bean>

<int:chain input-channel="cvsErrorChannel">
    <int:service-activator ref="cvsErrorMessageHandler" method="handleMessage"/>
</int:chain>

<stream:stderr-channel-adapter channel="errorChannel" append-newline="true"/>
```

---

```
<int:channel id="csdbInputChannel">
    <int:queue message-store="messageStore"/>
</int:channel>

<bean id="csdbService" class="com.renault.eplatform.transverse.datapower.csdb.ws.service.CsdbService">
    <property name="channel" ref="csdbInputChannel"/>
</bean>

<bean id="csdbWrapper" class="com.renault.eplatform.transverse.datapower.csdb.ws.wrapper.CsdbWrapper">
    <property name="httpClient">
        <bean class="com.fullsix.framework.net.http.HttpClientFactoryBean"/>
    </property>
    <property name="url" value="${www}"/>
    <property name="enumCountry" ref="currentCountry"/>
    <property name="datapowerLoggingService" ref="dxxx"/>
    <property name="password" value="${dwwww}"/>
    <property name="socketTimeout" value="20000"/>
    <property name="timeout" value="20000"/>
</bean>
```

---

> 201803-08 15:34:55,546 ERROR [ErrorHandler.java:28] - Try to fix data
>   on tables DATAPOWER_CSDB_MESSAGE_GROUP and DATAPOWER_CSDB_MESSAGE
>
> 201803-08 15:34:55,547 DEBUG
>   [AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:107]
>    - handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@4cc7014c]'
>   produced no reply for request Message:
>   [Payload=java.lang.NullPointerException][Headers={timestamp=1520519695543,
>   id=b71d066b-a8e5-4fa3-8b87-a8c1d9e57587}] 
>   201803-08 15:34:55,547
>   DEBUG [AbstractMessageChannel.java:237] - postSend (sent=true) on
>   channel 'csdbErrorChannel', message:
>   [Payload=java.lang.NullPointerException][Headers={timestamp=1520519695543,
>   id=b71d066b-a8e5-4fa3-8b87-a8c1d9e57587}] 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,515
>   DEBUG [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:365] - Creating new
>   transaction with name
>   201803-08 15:35:00,516 DEBUG
>   [SessionImpl.java:265] - opened session at timestamp: 15205197005
>
> 201803-08 15:35:00,517 DEBUG [HibernateTransactionManager.java:493] -
>   Opened new Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@7e350225] for
>   Hibernate transaction 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,517 DEBUG
>   [HibernateTransactionManager.java:504] - Preparing JDBC Connection of
>   Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@7e350225] 
>   201803-08
>   15:35:00,517 DEBUG [JDBCTransaction.java:78] - begin 
>   201803-08
>   15:35:00,518 DEBUG [ConnectionManager.java:444] - opening JDBC
>   connection 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,518 DEBUG [JDBCTransaction.java:83] -
>   current autocommit status: true 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,519 DEBUG
>   [JDBCTransaction.java:86] - disabling autocommit 
>   201803-08
>   15:35:00,519 DEBUG [HibernateTransactionManager.java:569] - Exposing
>   Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction
>   [jdbc:oracle:thin:@//active-db-valid:1521/rsite, UserName=RSITE_ES,
>   Oracle JDBC driver] 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,520 DEBUG
>   [JdbcTemplate.java:635] - Executing prepared SQL query 
>   201803-08
>   15:35:00,520 DEBUG [JdbcTemplate.java:570] - Executing prepared SQL
>   statement [SELECT COUNT(MESSAGE_ID) from DATAPOWER_CSDB_MESSAGE_GROUP
>   where GROUP_KEY=? AND REGION=?] 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,523 DEBUG
>   [JdbcTemplate.java:635] - Executing prepared SQL query 
>   201803-08
>   15:35:00,523 DEBUG [JdbcTemplate.java:570] - Executing prepared SQL
>   statement [SELECT MESSAGE_ID, CREATED_DATE from
>   DATAPOWER_CSDB_MESSAGE_GROUP where GROUP_KEY=? and REGION=? order by
>   UPDATED_DATE] 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,525 DEBUG [JdbcTemplate.java:635] -
>   Executing prepared SQL query 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,526 DEBUG
>   [JdbcTemplate.java:570] - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT
>   MESSAGE_ID, CREATED_DATE, MESSAGE_BYTES from DATAPOWER_CSDB_MESSAGE
>   where MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?] 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,528 DEBUG
>   [DefaultLobHandler.java:117] - Returning BLOB as bytes 
>   201803-08
>   15:35:00,529 DEBUG [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:843] -
>   Initiating transaction rollback 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,529 DEBUG
>   [HibernateTransactionManager.java:672] - Rolling back Hibernate
>   transaction on Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@7e350225]
>
> 201803-08 15:35:00,530 DEBUG [JDBCTransaction.java:182] - rollback
>
> 201803-08 15:35:00,531 DEBUG [JDBCTransaction.java:223] - re-enabling
>   autocommit 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,531 DEBUG [JDBCTransaction.java:193] -
>   rolled back JDBC Connection 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,531 DEBUG
>   [ConnectionManager.java:325] - transaction completed on session with
>   on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to
>   release JDBC resources! 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,532 DEBUG
>   [HibernateTransactionManager.java:734] - Closing Hibernate Session
>   [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@7e350225] after transaction 
>   201803-08
>   15:35:00,532 DEBUG [SessionFactoryUtils.java:800] - Closing Hibernate
>   Session 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,533 DEBUG [ConnectionManager.java:464] -
>   releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
>   (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)] 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,533 DEBUG
>   [ConnectionManager.java:325] - transaction completed on session with
>   on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to
>   release JDBC resources! 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,534 DEBUG
>   [AbstractMessageChannel.java:224] - preSend on channel
>   'csdbErrorChannel', message:
>   [Payload=java.lang.NullPointerException][Headers={timestamp=1520519700534,
>   id=fe974a6c-2351-4b95-ac6f-b98a0c02a7b3}] 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,534
>   DEBUG [AbstractMessageHandler.java:67] -
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0 received
>   message:
>   [Payload=java.lang.NullPointerException][Headers={timestamp=1520519700534,
>   id=fe974a6c-2351-4b95-ac6f-b98a0c02a7b3}] 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,535
>   DEBUG [AbstractMessageHandler.java:67] - ServiceActivator for
>   [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@4cc7014c]
>   received message:
>   [Payload=java.lang.NullPointerException][Headers={timestamp=1520519700534,
>   id=fe974a6c-2351-4b95-ac6f-b98a0c02a7b3}] 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,535 
>   INFO [ErrorHandler.java:25] - Error message handled 
>   201803-08
>   15:35:00,536 ERROR [ErrorHandler.java:27] -
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 
>   201803-08 15:35:00,536 ERROR
>   [ErrorHandler.java:28] - Try to fix data on tables
>   DATAPOWER_CSDB_MESSAGE_GROUP and DATAPOWER_CSDB_MESSAGE*

*

Comment: Your question is not clear; first step is to turn on DEBUG logging and follow the messages through the flow. If you still can't figure it out, explain the problem further and edit the question to add the logs.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I took time to read the documentation of spring integration, then I guess the problem is due to JDBC Message Store, he store messages with null payload in the database, and when the consumer tries to receive that's the wrong message, error handler Handel Exception message contains NullPointerException I think until this step is a correct behavior, but my question is why the receiver still blocked on this bad message (with payload null) and spring re-send error message on the channel, this behavior goes into a loop until I delete the bad message from database table.

Comment: If you throw an exception on the error flow, the transaction will roll back - you need to catch the NPE to avoid that.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I should catch NPE when i handle a message error !

Comment: Yes; in the error flow; if you need more help add a stack trace to your question.

Comment: yes;is jdbc transaction roll back no way to handle NPE on message error handler mybe i need to  ignore rollback when payload is null can i do that ? I edit my question

Comment: It's not clear how you can get `Payload=java.lang.NullPointerException`. It looks like your `CsdbService` is sending it - you really shouldn't be injecting channels into beans like that but I think that's where you are incorrectly sending such a message.

Comment: Anyway, we suppose csdbService can send null payload .As receiver why I can't manage that?spring integration doesn't support that! I will make column payload as a not null column but i continue to search thanks anyway

Comment: `null` payloads are not supported. Use a wrapper class for actual field if it can be `null`. `public class Foo { Object actualValueThatMightBeNull; }`.